# Typescript equivalent of beforesend in Javascript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to post a comment in my ionic app via wordpress api but it says error 401 (unauthorized) meaning Wordpress api thinks I am not logged in..

My code:

```
postComment(params?: any) {
let nonce = localStorage.getItem('nonce');
let seq = this.api.post('wp', 'comments', "post="+ params.post+ "&author_name="+params.author_name+"&author="+params.author+"&author_email=myemail@gmail.com&content=something").share();
  seq
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
    }, err => {
      console.error('ERROR', err);
    });
  return seq;
```

}

In my research it said that I have to send the nonce and I can do it like this:

```
.ajax( {
   url: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/posts/1',
   method: 'POST',
   beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
  },
    data:{
      'title' : 'Hello Moon'
  }
   }).done( function ( response ) {
});
```

How can I do this in typescript? How does one put a beforeSend function xhr.setRequestHeader in typescript form?

Comment: Just to be clear - this is a Angular vs. jQuery difference, not a TypeScript vs.  JavaScript difference,

Answer (score 0):

The setRequestHeader method set headers that are sent along with your request. The way this done in Ionic/Angular is to add a header object to the requestoptions parameters:

```
let opts: RequestOptionsArgs = {};
let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('X-WP-Nonce', nonce);
opts.headers = headers;

return this.http.post(fullPath, requestBody, opts)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Tried it and it says: Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers'/ Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated. Property 'keys' is missing in type 'Headers'.

Comment: Then you have a type mismatch, check your imports. The headers class should be imported from '@angular/http'. If you cant figure it out then add the code to the question and I can take a look